# How to globally activate useEffect in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am creating a chat application in React. I am using the useEffect-hook to update the messages (all it really does is fetch them from the JSON-server). I want them to be updated every time someone in the room sends a new message.

This is one alternative I have:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/messages/')
    .then(res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        data = data.filter((msg) => msg.room === room);
        setData(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
    })

    divRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

}, []);
```

"data" is a list of messages. This shows all the messages when you enter the room, but does not load when you pass a new message. Assumingly because of the empty list at the end. Therefore I tried this:

In another component, I have a variable "sent", which is set to true every time you send a message, like this:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {author: user, body: msg, room }
    setSent(true);

    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/messages/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => {
        response.json();
        setSent(false);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(`Error: ${err}`));

    setMsg('');
}
```

So every time you send a message, it is set to 'true', and as soon as it has been successfully sent, it is set back to 'false'. I then passed it as a prop to the component I use useEffect:

```
<div className='chat-main'>
    <Messages user={user} room={room} sent={sent} />
</div>
```

Then I put the "sent"-variable in the list at the bottom of the useEffect-hook. This updates the messages for the user who sends a message, but not for the others (because, of course, "sent" only changes if *you* send a message)

What can I do here? Is there a way?

Comment: what you are probably looking for is a way for your server to let your client know of some action, or provide an update. [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) are good for this, alternatively webhooks. There are a list of options at the bottom of the linked page.

Comment: You can also look into using AWS Amplify to set this up fairly quickly with AWS. A gentlemen named [Nader Dabit](https://github.com/dabit3) does some seriously good work on examples around this.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without websockets? I am currently using a simple JSON-server to save the messages

Comment: What server are you using? is it your own, or something like firebase?

Comment: The "server" is not a proper server. It is an npx JSON-server/database which contains the messages you send in each room.